# Node.JS get audio waveform samples

Tags: node.js, audio, buffer, server-side

I need get waveform samples by array of double numbers from audio file Buffer.
Only on server-side.

I was trying many ways and packages from internet, but they working only with AudioContext (Web-API), or doesn't work at all.

P.S. I saving audio file on server and create raw in database, and i also need to save in database array of number to fast drawing waveform on client before load audio file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.